# as measured by vs. measured by

Tags: usage

The following is a sentence extracted from an article from The New York Times.

> Districts with high suspension rates also tend to be correlated with
> lower student achievement as measured by test scores.

***as measured by*** is used idiomatically, right? I want to know the difference between ***as measured by*** and ***measured by***. What is the function of ***as*** in the phrase?

Answer (score 1):

"student achievement" doesn't have an obvious metric. What are the units?  Certainly not feet or liters. Maybe a good metric would be salaries after 10 years, or maybe 20 years. Or how many students end up in prison. Or how many children each student has in 10 years. Or homework scores.  Or surveys asking students, "Did you achieve?"  In your sentence, "as measured by" tells what criterion was used for determining whether student achievement was high or low, and the criterion was test scores.

"Measured by" would more likely be used to describe the measurement process. "Districts with high suspension rates also tend to be correlated with lower student achievement measured by administering the ACT to each student at the end of senior year, regardless of whether the student graduated.